# Has anyone worked with JSON in C++ in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have only previously worked with C++ in Visual Studio development environment. Now I have been asked to receive and send data using JSON.

I have searched the internet but can't find any example of JSON being used by C++ in Visual Studio. If anyone has worked with JSON in C++ in Visual Studio 2010 please pass on the link.

Comment: Try this: [Json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11) or [PicoJSON](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson). No BOOST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will install boost::spirit you can use this lib [JSON Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented). Works in with VS like a charm.

**UPDATE** Include json spirit directory and use

```
#include <json_spirit/json_spirit.h>
#include <json_spirit/json_spirit_reader_template.h>
#include <json_spirit/json_spirit_writer_template.h>
```

Comment: How to install boost::spirit,can you please guide?

Comment: i downloaded he project given on the link  JSON Spirit.It includes five project,can you just tell me please which one takes the JSON OBJECT as argument that i get from one of my method of C# DLL an parse it and store it in a file.

Comment: are you for real ? you know that c++ is not c# right ?

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds JFYI it's possible to call functions and even pass data between C++(unmanaged) and C# (managed).

Answer (score 1):

[JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) is a C++ JSON parser that builds in VS according to their [README](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/README.txt).

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) supports JSON. This is a nice alternative, because in addition to JSON, you also get transport mechanisms (TCP sockets, etc) and optionally in a multi-threaded environment.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json) you can find info about JSON for windows.

Thrift is multi-platform, so it should work quite well with VS.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [rapidjson](http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/).

It is small, fast, natively support VC2008/2010, with minimal dependencies (e.g. no BOOST, not even STL).

It can parse and generate JSON using SAX or DOM style API.

Answer (score 0):

[Json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11) - is a tiny JSON library for C++11, providing JSON parsing and serialization.

The core object provided by the library is json11::Json. A Json object represents any JSON value: null, bool, number (int or double), string (std::string), array (std::vector), or object (std::map).

Json objects act like values. They can be assigned, copied, moved, compared for equality or order, and so on. There are also helper methods Json::dump, to serialize a Json to a string, and Json::parse (static) to parse a std::string as a Json object.

Example:

```
        const string simple_test =
            R"({"k1":"v1", "k2":42, "k3":["a",123,true,false,null]})";
        string err;
        auto json = Json::parse(simple_test, err);
        std::cout << "k1: " << json["k1"].string_value() << "\n";
```

---

[PicoJSON](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) - is a tiny JSON parser / serializer for C++ with following properties:

- header-file only
- no external dependencies (only uses standard C++ libraries)
- STL-frendly (arrays are represented by using std::vector, objects are std::map)
- provides both pull interface and streaming (event-based) interface

Example:

```
        std::string json1 = R"({ "k1":"v1", "k2" : 42, "k3" : ["a",123,true,false,null] })";
        picojson::value v;
        std::string err1 = picojson::parse(v, json1);
        const picojson::object& o = v.get<picojson::object>();
        for (picojson::object::const_iterator i = o.begin(); i != o.end(); ++i) {
            std::cout << i->first << "  " << i->second << std::endl;
        }
```

Both easily used in Visual Studio with standard libriries (NO any additional dependencies).